# C# Serial Port + CCS C Serial Port + PIC 16F877A

Tags: c#, c, serial-port, pic

I have a PIC 16F887A connected to the serial port. I want it to lit a green led when it receives 0x01 and lit a red led when it receives 0x00 from pc. I send the characters from a C# windows forms application, the PIC itself is programmed with CCS C. Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong as the codes below don't work?

Edit: By doesn't work i mean it lits the red led in both cases.

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace deneme
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void openportbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }

            if (!port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Open();
            }
        }

        private void rightbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] right = new byte[1];
            right[0] = 0x01;
            port.Write(right, 0, right.Length);
        }

        private void wrongbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] wrong = new byte[1];
            wrong[0] = 0x00;
            port.Write(wrong, 0, wrong.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

CCS C Code

```
#include <16f877A.h>

#fuses XT,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOBROWNOUT,NOLVP,NOPUT,NOWRT,NODEBUG,NOCPD

#use delay (clock=4000000)

#use rs232 (baud=9600, xmit=pin_c6, rcv=pin_c7, parity=N, stop=1, bits=8)

char received;
char right = 0x01;

#int_rda
void serial_interrupt()
{
   disable_interrupts(int_rda);
   received = getc();
   if(received == right)
   {
      output_high(pin_c5); //green led
      delay_ms(200);
      output_low(pin_c5);
   }
   else
   {
      output_high(pin_c4); //red led
      delay_ms(200);
      output_low(pin_c4);
   }
}

void main()
{
   setup_psp(PSP_DISABLED);
   setup_timer_1(T1_DISABLED);
   setup_timer_2(T2_DISABLED,0,1);
   setup_adc_ports(NO_ANALOGS);
   setup_adc(ADC_OFF);
   setup_CCP1(CCP_OFF);
   setup_CCP2(CCP_OFF);

   output_low(pin_c4);
   output_low(pin_c5);

   enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);
   while(1)
   {
      enable_interrupts(int_rda);
   }
}
```

Comment: Which value do you actually receive in the 'right' case? What happens if you change the test to be `if(received != 0)` instead than `if(received == right)`?

Comment: I'm using Proteus ISIS simulation (with virtual serial port drivers). In the 'right' case i see 01 at the Proteus virtual terminal but it still lits the red one. And it now works properly when i use if(received != 0) in the C code, thanks. Original code also seems legit but why doesn't it work right, any idea?

Comment: Maybe the bits are read in the reverse order - so you send `0x01` and receive `0x80`, or there is some problem with parity, so you send `0x01` and receive `0x02` because the parity bit shifted everything...it has been a long long time since I worked with serial ports, but I remember they can be tricky

Comment: The bit order on a UART is well defined, so that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The pic properly acts only to 0x00, so i guess you're right. If i find the cause of the problem or find a solution, i will post it here. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: However, if your baud rate is miscalculated somehow, then the 0x01 sent LSB could stretch out to 0x03 to the view of the PIC.  It would be interesting to see what the value is in `received`... could you put a breakpoint in there?

Comment: I just connected an LCD to the pic. In the right case it shows a left arrow '←', in the wrong case it shows nothing.

Comment: I just tried sending 'y' and 'n' characters from C# to pic instead of 0x01 and 0x00. On the PIC side, they appeared as 'C' and '$' respectively.

Comment: 'y' is 0x79 is 0b01111001 and transmitted 10011110.  The clock rate would have to be really screwed up to get 'C' which is 0x43 and transmitted 11000010.  Do you have access to an oscilloscope?  Also, where are you initializing the UART?  It seems like you haven't set the baud rate correctly.  Could you post that code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10606/discussion-between-adam-casey-and-omerta)

Comment: After a few hours of tinkering, i found out that the max232 (the chip used for rs232-ttl conversion) was causing the issue. There's nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

If it receives 0x00 in both cases, it is likely that you have a baud rate mismatch, even a slight one.  After detecting a start bit, the PIC might be seeing the first 7 zeroes and think it saw 8, going you 0x00 in both cases.  I would try transmitting from the PIC and PC and watching the lines on a scope to ensure they are running the same speed.  You can also try continuously transmitting 0xAA to get an eye pattern (10101010) and comparing the two signals.

Comment: Another option is to connect PIC's rx and tx pins and send 0 and 1 from the PIC itself and see if it can turn the right LEDs on and off. If it can't, there's a problem with the PIC's program.